# Encrypted OS and resize partition during installation Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, resize

I have question, I have 120GB ssd and I want to install Ubuntu and encrypt this installation, I also need to resize this encrypted system partition to 40GB and rest leave for something else. I am trying to it when installing Ubuntu but when I will choose encryption then I can’t resize partition or when I choose to resize then I can’t encrypt this partition. Can you tell me please what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You can't use the guided installation for this scenario. You will need to choose "something else" during installation and manually partition.

Comment: Make the partition changes you want before starting the installer (you didn't mention an OS/release/flavor but there are 2 or 3 tools on each ISO that will do it).; just as Nmath has said.

Comment: I have ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64. I know that I can choose "something else" during installation and manually partition ssd but this option wont let me encrypt installation. I googled that I could encrypt system after OS is installed but I am not Terminal expert, I rather would like to use something with GUI. Is there any GUI  software to encrypt all system ?